# load image by picasso in recyclerview by databinding kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I want to use `databinding` to load image by `Picasso` in `recycler view` but when I don't know how to use  `@BindingAdapter` in my `recycler view` `data class`. I know how it is worked in java but in kotlin I don't know how to use it. This is my data class for my adapter:

```
data class Users(val name: String,
             val email: String,
             val img_link: String)
```

And this is my adapter:

```
class AdapterRecPart02(private val context: Context, private val ls: List<Users>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecPart02.ItemAdapter>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemAdapter {

    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val binding: LayoutRecPart02Binding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.layout_rec_part02, parent, false)
    return ItemAdapter(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemAdapter, position: Int) {

    holder.bind(ls[position])

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = ls.size


inner class ItemAdapter(private val bindingAdapter: LayoutRecPart02Binding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindingAdapter.root) {

    fun bind(user: Users) {

        bindingAdapter.users = user
        bindingAdapter.executePendingBindings()

    }


}
```

}

And this is my custom layout for my adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="users"
        type="ir.xs.mvvm.model.Users" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_user"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_user"
        android:text="@{users.name, default = name}"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_user"
        android:text="@{users.email, default = email}"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple binding adapter that will use Picasso to load an image:

```
@BindingAdapter("urlImage")
fun bindUrlImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
    if (imageUrl != null) {
        Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(view)
    } else {
        view.setImageBitmap(null)
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use this binding adapter in a data binding layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:binding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
    
    <data>

        <variable
            name="imageUrl"
            type="String" />


    </data>
    
    
    //.......
    
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                binding:urlImage="@{ imageUrl }" />
                
</layout>
```

For the specific case in the question, here is how you would bind the image url:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_user"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    binding:urlImage="@{ users.img_link }" />
```

Comment: where should I place it: fun bindUrlImage ? And also I am trying to use mvvm in this. Is This proper for mvvm?

Comment: @poya4220 Typically you would put binding adapters in a separate file that doesn't have any class, similar to a file that just has extension functions.  Something like `BindingAdapters.kt` or something more specific if you're organizing them in some way.  As for using MVVM correctly, just make sure that your source data is being provided by `LiveData` that is provided by a ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help